# xubuntu desktop breaks on tightvncserver

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu, vnc, remote-access, tightvncserver

I have a desktop PC I want to remote desktop to, I also like the concept of virtual displays, so no one can see what I'm doing as I do it unless they connect to the display (as opposed to the standard vino setup where whatever I do would be shown on any real displays attached to the PC).

The problem is I that when I connect to it, the desktop seems broken, the theme goes gray (windows 95 style) and some icons are even missing (see image below).

My xstartup script looks like:

```
$ cat .vnc/xstartup 
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
#export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
#/etc/X11/Xsession
#exec ck-launch-session startxfce4
startxfce4 &
#xfce4-session &
```

Please help,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You properly missing this line on your ubuntu xstartup file

```
vncconfig -iconic &
```

I use this xstartup file and xfce displays everything correctly

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but this actually didn't work, now in all fairness, the system I'm using to test is quite outdated (xubuntu 13.10 not-so-fresh install - it's behind a wallgarden with no access to the internet). I'll try this on an updated VM later and let you know of the results